# ¿Cómo puedo validar el ingreso de datos en un input para que sea solo números?, detalle adicional: el input no es nativo - Angular

Tags: angular10

Tengo un fragmento de código en una directiva que recolecté, pero solo me sirve para input nativos, en el html utilizo una libreria llamada ng-select, no es nativo de angular y por ende no funciona el nativeElement para controlar los caracteres de entrada.

```js
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent {

    selectedCar: number;

    cars = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Volvo' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Saab' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Opel' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Audi' },
    ];
}
```

```html
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id">{{car.name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>

<!--Using items input-->
<ng-select [items]="cars" 
           bindLabel="name" 
           bindValue="id" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Podrias agregar lo que tenes y mostrarnos ese input no nativo como para que tengamos idea de que hablas y asi ayudarte?

Comment: <ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id">{{car.name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>


<ng-select [items]="cars" 
           bindLabel="name" 
           bindValue="id" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
</ng-select>

Comment: Pon el código _en la pregunta_, con el formato correspondiente, no en los comentarios. Para ello, pulsa en [edit].